# iPad web app Full screen in Desktop version

Tags: css, ios, ipad

I have web page which works fine on browser on device but when i save to home screen to that web page and open from that  there exits  some screen sizing issue while opening it from icon from desktop.how to settle this.

My css code is below

```
     *, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, li, img, nav, header, section {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
    }


   /* Styles */
     body {
     width:2048px;
     height:748px;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
position:absolute;
width: 2048px; margin:0; 
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
padding: 0;
    }

   .panel{
background-image:url(image/testing_file_1.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:748px;
width:1024px;
position:relative;
float: left;
padding:0;
bottom:0;
top:0;
margin:0;
display:inline;
}
   .main_heading{
float:left;
margin:47px 0 0 60px;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
    }
    .main_heading_two{
float:left;
margin:47px 0 0 60px;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
    }
   .menu {
float:right;
margin: 39px 18px 0 0;
height:47px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    .menu ul li {
list-style:none;
float:left;
    }

    .menu ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
    }

    .menu .active {
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url();
    }

   .menu .stix {
width:2px;
font-size:0px;
background-image:url(image/seperator.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:0;
height:47px;
    }

    .midmenu {
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
height:62px;
width:61px;
margin: 248px 0 0 0;

    }
   .midmenu1 {
float:right;
list-style-type:none;
height:62px;
width:61px;
margin: 248px -500px 0 0px;
   }

   .rightclass img{
padding: 2px 20px;
float:right;
width:459px;
height:560px;
z-index:10;}
   .text_paragraph{
float:left;
width:450px;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:80px;
margin-top:-525px;
   }
   .text_paragraph_1{
float:left;
width:420px;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:80px;
margin-top:-464px;
    }
   .text_paragraph_1 ul{
float:left;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:5px;
    }
   .text_paragraph_1 ul li{
margin-top:5px;
    }
    .text_paragraph_2{
float:left;
width:450px;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:80px;
margin-top:-285px;
   }
    .text_paragraph_2 ul{
float:left;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:5px;
   }
   .text_paragraph_2 ul li{
margin-top:5px;
font-style:italic;
   }
   .text_paragraph_2 p{
float:left;
color:#FFF;
margin-top:5px;
   }
   .linkbutton{
margin:-70px 0 0 70px;
float:left;}
   small
   {
font-size:9px;
    }






   .rightclass_one img{
margin: 2px 21px;
float:right;
width:459px;
height:560px;
z-index:10;}
    .midmenu_1 {
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
height:62px;
width:61px;
margin: -45px 0 0 0;

    }
    .midmenu_2 {
float:right;
list-style-type:none;
height:62px;
width:61px;
margin: -45px -500px 0 0px;
    }
    .right_text{
float:right;
color:#000;
margin-right:-470px;
width:440px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:-270px;}
   .image_21{

   float:right;
    margin-right:-390px;
    margin-top:-190px;}

   .ratemeter{
float:right;
margin-right:-410px;
margin-top:20px;}
   .image_one{
  float:right;
  margin-right:-450px;
  margin-top:92px;
  z-index:5;
   }
 .image_two{
 float:right;
 margin-top:93px;
 margin-right:-254px;
 z-index:10;
  }
   .image_one_one{
 float:right;
 margin-top:95px;
 margin-right:-317px;
 z-index:10;
 }
 .image_two_two{
  float:right;
  margin-right:-452px;
  margin-top:92px;
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, please elaborate or restate.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i want that when i open this web app in safari it looks fine because it is set with the address bar postion or it normally looks on browser but when i open this after adding to Homescreen the addrees bar is hidden and page is lifted from bottom to up an dit has space from bottom size due to address bar removal

Comment: @Michael Dautermann i want that when i open this web app in safari it looks fine because it is set with the address bar postion or it normally looks on browser but when i open this after adding to Homescreen the addrees bar is hidden and page is lifted from bottom to up an dit has space from bottom size due to address bar removal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... that's completely clear, why you've got a fixed height... in your body you set height to 748px... thats not variable.
Try something like this:

I used this in my webapp and it worked fine:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    min-height: 416px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

I tried to edit your code, but i don't know, if it will work for you. please have a try:

```
 body {
     width:2048px;
     min-height:748px;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: hidden;
     font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

     -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in your head from your webpage:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
```

Comment: i have put this also but again it shows space from the bottom of the web page when page is opened form home or desktop of the ipad device

Comment: why do you post everything two times??